# I got abit trouble with SQL Server PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot, max, min

I have got a bit trouble with a SQL Server query. You can see in my result, at column Level 1, there is a record "Level 1 activity", but actually there are 3 records "Level 1 activity, Level 1 activity second, and Level 1 activity third". With my command `MIN(activityName)`, it shows 1 only.

I wonder that do we have any other ways to show the data like that with 3 records?

```
SELECT 
   strandName as [Strand Name], 
   scopeName as [Scope Name], 
   FoundationLevel as [Foundation Level], 
   Level1 as [Level 1]
FROM 
    (select 
         st.strandName, s.scopeName, l.levelNo, activityName 
     from 
          strands as st 
     inner join 
          scopes as s on st.id = s.strandID 
     left join 
          activities as a on s.id = a.scopeID 
     left join 
          levels as l on a.levelID = l.id where unitID = 2) up 
PIVOT 
     (min(activityName) FOR levelNo IN (FoundationLevel, Level1)) AS pvt 
ORDER BY 
    scopeName
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can create column from records with IN using pivot

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T
     AS (select strandName as [Strand Name] , scopeName as [Scope Name] , FoundationLevel as [Foundation Level] , Level1 as [Level 1]

FROM (select st.strandName, s.scopeName, l.levelNo, activityName from strands as st 

inner join scopes as s on st.id = s.strandID 

left join activities as a on s.id = a.scopeID 

left join levels as l on a.levelID = l.id where unitID = 2) 

SELECT *
FROM   T PIVOT (min(activityName)
FOR levelNo IN (Level 1 activity, Level 1 activity second, Level 1 activity third) ) AS pvt
ORDER  BY OrderID
```